# UITableView with image change after scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm trying to create a custom UITableView with different cell identifiers. In the first cell should display an image and below to follow the rest of the cells. However when after scrolling the displayed image disappears. I tried to solve by looking for the answers provided by others for similar problems but without success.

Here's the code.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    EventoCell *cell;
    static NSMutableString *CellIdentifier;
    if(i==0){
        CellIdentifier = @"imgCell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        i++;
    }
    else{
       CellIdentifier = @"CellaEvento";
       cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

       cell.Nome.text=[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetEvento];
       cell.Localita.text=[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetLocalita];
       cell.Ora.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetOra],[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetMinuti]];

       [cell setValue:[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetEvento] :[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetGiorno] :[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetMese] :[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetAnno] :[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetOra] :[[AShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]GetMinuti]];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the i variable you are using? If you are trying to use that so that you know which cell you are in then it is not correct. you should be using indexPath.row

Comment: is i an instance variable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to display image in the first row? If so, I think you can change the line for judge whether it is the first row from

```
if ( i==0 )
```

to

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0)
```

I think the i must be a class member. The `UITableView` only creates limited number of `UITableViewCell`. Commonly, the number equals to to the number of displaying rows. For example, if the screen can only display 10 rows, `UITableView` creates 10 cell. After scrolling, It reuses the created cells by calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`, this makes the rows which are out of screen release their cells. When scroll back, each "new" entered item needs a cell. The `UITableView` will call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` for new cell. Therefore as your scenario, only the first time, the image row can be displayed, because after the first time, the i is non-zero even scroll back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Now everything works! I guessed that the problem could also be the fact I had tried some solutions but unable to solve. Thanks for the explanation of the functioning of the UITableView, really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "i" was used as an instance variable in your code. Instead you should rely to the indexPath variable passed as an argument of the  `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Your very first item in your table view is identified by:

```
 indexPath.row == 0 and indexPath.section == 0
```

.row is a row index within a given section .section

Make sure you have correctly implemented those two delegate methods also to correctly identify respectively your number of rows within a section and your number of sections:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```